# Cannot reach any other device in the same subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, subnet

The situation is:

- All devices are wireless devices
- Subnet: 192.168.50.x
- Default Route: 192.168.50.1
- Subnet Mask for all devices: 255.255.255.0
- Router -ping-> Any device: Work
- Any device -ping-> Router: Work
- Any device -ping-> Another device: Doesn't work

Well, I'm not a newbie and based on my knowledge, I think it is all correct. Cannot really figure out anything wrong.

Thanks for any help! And btw I'm using ASUS RT-AC86U as my router but I've enabled the communication between wireless devices.

Comment: “I've enabled the communication between wireless devices.” – You sure? Because usually, that’s the default behavior. The opposite, so-called “AP Isolation” is a behavior that can be “enabled”.

Comment: @DanielB Sorry about the confusion but I do mean "AP Isolation" is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Connect affected devices to an Ethernet port on this unit to ensure it's not happening with a wired connection
- If it is reproducible with a wired connection, ensure firewalls are disabled or that ICMP is allowed on both devices, especially if they are Windows 10 systems.
- On this router you might need to disable AP isolation on both the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz bands (each may have separate settings).
- Last, ensure the router's firmware is up to date, then factory-reset the router, try again.

Comment: Good advice! I will test your first one and last one, and for the second and third ones. As I can ping any device from the router, I think firewalls are not the problem. And I do disabled "AP Isolation".